# How can we a get a tab element when the document is known?

Tags: javascript, gwt, firefox-addon, jsni

Before explaining the question, I want to explain my main goal (If there is a better way than my approach):

I have the *document* element available with me and ideally I wanted to get a browser element such that it identifies a tab uniquely. In my previous approach I used

```
gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument(doc);
```

This returned the browser which was indeed unique to the tab (in the sense that attributes stored in it persisted across pages). 
If instead, I don't store the browser element, and after moving to *another page in the same tab* I try the above command again, then the browser is no longer the same one as before (in the sense that it has lost all the stored attributes).

Therein lies my main problem. I want to get hold of the tab browser which I am able to refer to using different documents loaded in the same tab.

I read about a similar function:

```
gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(tab);
```

I have a feeling this might work. But again, I am not able to understand where I can get the parameter "tab" from (given a document).

Note: I am using GWT for the development of the extension

---

**EDIT:** To clarify the intent of the question, here's the *use case* as well as my approach:

In my extension, I am interested in monitoring user behaviour on particular websites. In a way it can be thought of as a *session* which remains active until the user stays on the same website. During the session, I am often required to store various attributes specific to user behaviour. One of the attributes concerning the question in "isSessionActive":"Y" or "" (blank string stands for no)

To make the code more optimal, I do not instantiate a browser for all the tabs in the beginning. Instead, I wait for the cue using an onLoad function. : if a relevant website is visited

Once that happens, I make a call to get the browser using the current document element, see if it has a non empty value for the attribute isSessionActive. If it does not, I set the attributes value to "Y" and instantiate my class which handles the profiling after that.

If it has value "Y", I know that the session is still active and that I don't need to initialize.

The problem which I'm facing is that after the first instantiation, when I move to another page within the same tab, I expected that the call to 
    gBrowser.getBrowserforDocument(doc);

would get me the browser instantiated previously since it is basically the same tab.

This is not happening. Each time I get a new Browser instance which does not have the attribute isSessionActive as "Y" (probably because the new page has a new document element). Thus, at present all my code instantiates over and over again which is what I do not want.

Comment: I deleted my answer - I misunderstood your question. `gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument(doc)` correctly returns the `<xul:browser>` element for me and that element doesn't change if the user navigates to a different page. So the issue must be with the way you attach data to the browser element. How do you do it?

Comment: @WladimirPalant I have updated the question explaining my scenario. Further I attact data to the browser using GWT's method browser.setAttribute(String key,String val); The browser element does respond to browser.getAttribute(string key). But as explained in edit, my main problem is that I am not able to get the correct browser element again (given a doc)

Comment: Double check with the DOM Inspector to see if the browser element still has the attribute on a new content page load.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only working with the current tab (and not any background tabs), then you could just use gBrowser.selectedTab https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#p-selectedTab

Comment: I thought he had the content document and wanted to get the corresponding tab.